# The 'xs:group' start tag on line 21 position 4 does not match the end tag of 'xr:group'

Tags: xml, linq, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working with MVC3 project and when deployed to production Im getting this error

```
The 'xs:group' start tag on line 21 position 4 does not match the end tag of 'xr:group'. Line 30, position 5.
```

Stacktrace below

```
    at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.Throw(String res, String[] args)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ThrowTagMismatch(NodeData startTag)
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseEndElement()
   at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.ParseElementContent()
   at System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchema.Read(XmlReader reader, ValidationEventHandler validationEventHandler)
   at System.Data.EntityModel.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.SomSchemaSetHelper.AddXmlSchemaToSet(XmlSchemaSet schemaSet, XmlSchemaResource schemaResource, HashSet`1 schemasAlreadyAdded)
   at System.Data.EntityModel.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.SomSchemaSetHelper.ComputeSchemaSet(SchemaDataModelOption dataModel)
   at System.Data.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.Result.GetValue()
   at System.Data.Common.Utils.Memoizer`2.Evaluate(TArg arg)
   at System.Data.EntityModel.SchemaObjectModel.Schema.Parse(XmlReader sourceReader, String sourceLocation)
   at System.Data.EntityModel.SchemaObjectModel.SchemaManager.ParseAndValidate(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 sourceFilePaths, SchemaDataModelOption dataModel, AttributeValueNotification providerNotification, AttributeValueNotification providerManifestTokenNotification, ProviderManifestNeeded providerManifestNeeded, IList`1& schemaCollection)
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EdmItemCollection.LoadItems(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 sourceFilePaths, SchemaDataModelOption dataModelOption, DbProviderManifest providerManifest, ItemCollection itemCollection, Boolean throwOnError)
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.EdmItemCollection.Init(IEnumerable`1 xmlReaders, IEnumerable`1 filePaths, Boolean throwOnError)
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.EdmMetadataEntry.LoadEdmItemCollection(MetadataArtifactLoader loader)
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.LoadItemCollection[T](IItemCollectionLoader`1 itemCollectionLoader, T entry)
   at System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataCache.GetOrCreateEdmItemCollection(String cacheKey, MetadataArtifactLoader loader, Object& entryToken)
   at System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetMetadataWorkspace(Boolean initializeAllCollections)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(EntityConnection connection, Boolean isConnectionConstructor)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalConnection.CreateObjectContextFromConnectionModel()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.InitializeContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType(Type entityType)
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.get_InternalContext()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1.System.Linq.IQueryable.get_Provider()
   at System.Linq.Queryable.Join[TOuter,TInner,TKey,TResult](IQueryable`1 outer, IEnumerable`1 inner, Expression`1 outerKeySelector, Expression`1 innerKeySelector, Expression`1 resultSelector)
   at FRMobileApplication.Controllers.PreScreenController.GetClientDetails(String jobCode) in C:\Users\AAM\Documents\Choy Projects\FRMobile\FRMobileApplication\FRMobileApplication\Controllers\PreScreenController.cs:line 492
   at FRMobileApplication.Controllers.PreScreenController.PreScreen() in C:\Users\AAM\Documents\Choy Projects\FRMobile\FRMobileApplication\FRMobileApplication\Controllers\PreScreenController.cs:line 30
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12()
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String actionName)
```

This page works in the other domain. also tried to add System.Xml.Linq but still no luck.
Thanks in advance.

I have this method GetClientDetails() that executed LINQ, it seems that the error is caused by that LINQ, I used EF4.

```
using (frEntities db = new frEntities())
{
    var client = (from c in db.CLIENTs
                  join p in db.POSITIONs on c.CLIENT_ID equals p.CLIENT_ID
                  join cf in db.Client_Features on c.CLIENT_ID equals cf.Client_ID
                  where p.POSITION_JobCode == jobCode
                  select new{
                      c.CLIENT_ID,
                      p.POSITIONTYPE_ID
                  }).FirstOrDefault();
 }
```

**Answer Update**

I got it working, we just updated the EF4 to EF6.1 and fixed some references.

Answer (score 0):

I should think the error means exactly what it says.

The 'xs:group' start tag on line 21 position 4 does not match the end tag of 'xr:group'. Line 30, position 5.

On line 21 you will find

```
   <xs:group>
```

and on line 30 you will find

```
   </xr:group>
```

So your XML is not well formed. No XML parser should allow this through without error.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working, we just updated the EF4 to EF6.1 and fixed some references.